# ASP.net unexpected error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code and I want that whenever the user clicks on his/her name, it opens a Manage account page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.Name + "" ,"Manage", "Account" ,routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

However, although I have created a Manage.cshtml view, I still receive the error 404. 
[image]

Comment: Did you create an ActionResult on the AccountController that returns the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Action into your controller

```
public ActionResult Manage()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But for some reason, my Manage view is empty, although I have data, do you perhaps know why?
Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ecb6d748fdaf9307fa182a985a71787

Comment: You need to return your model to fill your form

return View(employeeModel);

Comment: Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            return View(employee);

So I wrote this code, but still nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: And I also used var employee = db.Employees; and still nothing

Comment: Where you get the id value? You can insert as a querystring parameter like that Manager(int id) and change the link builder to generate with this parameter routeValues: new { id = your_employee_id_goes_here }